# How to access property in extended class in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, class, if-statement, coffeescript, extends

I want to use `@Type` in a if statement, but it seems as if it is not recognizing `@Type`. Is there a way to get `@Type` so that I can use it in the superclass?

```
class opponent
    constructor: (ID, Level, Name) ->
        @ID = ID
        @Level = Level
        @Name = Name
        @Health = if @Level is 1
            @Level * 5 
        else if 2 <= @Level <= 4
            (@Level * 6) - (@Level * 2)  
        @Luck = if @Type is "Snake"
            Math.ceil(@Level * 1.25) + 5
        else
            Math.ceil(@Level * 1.25)
        @attackDamage = 0
        @defenseDoubled = false;
        @Poisoned = false;
        @Burned = false;
        @Frozen = false;

    @defend: ->
        @Defense *= 2
        @DefenseDoubled = true;
    @undefend: ->
        @Defense /= 2
        @DefenseDoubled = false;

class Snake extends opponent
    @Type: "Snake"
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Snake` set `@Health` itself?  A parent class shouldn't know anything about possible extensions.

Comment: @hpaulj I was trying to avoid that because I will be making more classes that extend from opponent, but I guess it might be easier to do that

Comment: The `@Type: "Snake"` line makes a (to borrow Java terminology) static variable.  If you want it to be non-static, you would use `Type: "Snake"`.  Is there a reason you're not doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question (of how to make a subclass attribute visible to the parent class), but it should produce the same result - in a manner that easily expands.  You can add more subclasses without going back and changing `opponent` each time.

```
class opponent
    constructor: (ID, Level, Name) ->
        @ID = ID
        @Level = Level
        @Name = Name
        @Health = if @Level is 1
            @Level * 5 
        else if 2 <= @Level <= 4
            (@Level * 6) - (@Level * 2)  
        @Luck = Math.ceil(@Level * 1.25)
        @attackDamage = 0
        # ...

class Snake extends opponent
    constructor : (ID, Level, Name) ->
      # use parent constructor to create the object
      # and then customize the values for this class
      super
      @Luck = Math.ceil(@Level * 1.25) + 5
```

Comment: To make it even more simple and future-proof, you would implement the @Luck calculation in the **opponent** class and only define some kind of *luck modifier* in the subclasses, so that the subclass does not have to worry about how the luck is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the "class" using the [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

> Returns a reference to the `Object` function that created the instance's prototype.

So if `s` is a snake, then `s.constructor` is `Snake`. That means that you can do things like this:

```
class A
    m: -> console.log(@constructor.type)

class B extends A
    @type = 'B'

class C extends A
    @type = 'C'

(new B).m()
(new C).m()
```

and get `'B'` and `'C'` in the console.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bE6jh/

In your particular case, you'd want to look at `@constructor.Type` inside the method that wants to know the type.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because in the parent class, you are referencing an instance variable, `@Type`, but in the *Snake* subclass, you are defining a class variable, `@Type: "Snake"`.

To declare the `Type` variable as instance variable, declare it without the `@` sign:

```
class Snake extends opponent
  Type: "Snake"
```

To further expand on hpaulj's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21887879/2019265) - you always want to keep your code DRY, so the logic that calculates the @Luck attribute should be only defined in the parent class. Consider the following example:

```
class opponent
  constructor: ( args... ) ->
  # ... your logic
  @Luck = Math.ceil(@Level * 1.25) + ( @LuckFactor? or 0 )

class Snake extends opponent
  LuckFactor: 5
```